# TomEE not finding JPA 2.1 classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I am developing an RESTful application and want to deploy it on TomEE server. Everything is fine before I do request to the server when it throws some exceptions with root: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery`. I have searched the internet for it but couldn't find anything. Also I am not using hibernate

Edit: Posting my configs.

pom.xml:

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>JobManager-core</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>JobManager-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../JobManager-parent/</relativePath>
</parent>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.eclipsesource.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>provider-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>`
```

persistence.xml

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JobManager-core"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.sap.manager.app.entities.Job</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\I322829\Derby\MyDB\Manager;create=true" />

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
            value="database" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Edit 2: I have not showed my pom.xml for the RESTful api because it is working with my filesystem (starts throwing exceptions after I switch to Database).

Comment: post your relevant configs.

Comment: if you want to use the JPA API v2.1 then you need to put that jar in the CLASSPATH. Look under "org.eclipse.persistence" for something like javax.persistence or persistence-api.

Comment: @Neil: OP is using TomEE, not Tomcat. Moreover, "CLASSPATH" is only relevant for Java SE based CLI applications. OP is trying to use a Java EE web application archive.

Comment: CLASSPATH is relevant for any Java process, and is the cause of ClassNotFoundException. Yes in JavaEE you put things in different places but that is simply the container arranging the runtime CLASSPATH for you. Those classes have to be present either way.

Comment: Java's runtime classpath is formally spelled out "classpath". The CLI environment variable is called CLASSPATH. Exactly that environment variable is irrelevant in any Java SE/EE application archive and is the source of many confusions and misleadings among starters. Please be careful with that, or a starter would cluelessly fiddle around with environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

TomEE officially supports JavaEE 6, whereas `@StoredProcedureQuery` is only available since JavaEE 7. If you want to use this new version of API, specifically using eclipselink, you need to include eclipselink into to WAR application. Or, you may put this eclipselink into TomEE server installation to be available for the application. A side note: be aware, that TomEE uses OpenJPA library to provide JPA functionality, your application seems to request eclipselink, therefore it would be a good thing to include eclipselink either in the app server or in the app, even if TomEE supported the newest JPA version.